# Dynamically select database based on request

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to keep my RESTful site DRY, and I can't come up with a good way to factor out the code to dynamically select from each "user's" separate database. We've got a separate database for each client. This comes in as a part of the URL, and is passed into each view as a keyword arg. I want to give each and every view the behavior of accessing the corresponding database WITHOUT have to make sure each programmer writing a view remembers to use

```
Thing.objects.using(user).all()
```

and

```
t = Thing()
t.save(using=user)
```

every time. It seems like there ought to be some way to intercept the request and set the default database based on the args to the view *before* it hits the view, allowing us to use the usual

```
Thing.objects.all()
```

This would also have the advantage of factoring out all the user resolution code into a more appropriate place.

Answer (score 1):

We do this by the following technique.

1. Apache picks off the first part of the path and routes this to a specific mod_wsgi Daemon.
2. Each mod_wsgi daemon is a different customer's installation.

We have many parallel customers, each with (nearly) identical code, all based off a single common installation of the base software.

Each customer has a separate `settings.py` with their unique configuration.

They don't (actually can't) know about each other because Apache has peeled off the top layer of the path for us.

Comment: this was going to be my suggestion.